# How to remove duplicate titles while scraping it from web-page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I Want to remove duplicate `titles` to be removed from the output, i am using Beautiful soup to **scrape** the titles.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


    source = requests.get('https://itrevolution.com/book-downloads-extra-materials/')
    source = source.text
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    
    for tl in soup.find_all('img', class_='responsive-img hover-img'):
      title = set()
      title = tl.get('title')
      print('{}'.format(title))
```

**Output:**  Output from the above script..

```
Accelerate
Team Topologies
Accelerate
Project to Product
War and Peace and IT
A Seat at the Table
The Art of Business Value
DevOps for the Modern Enterprise
Making Work Visible
Leading the Transformation
The DevOps Handbook
The Phoenix Project
Beyond the Phoenix Project
```

We have title `Accelerate`  which appears twice which needs to be appear one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, taking advantage of a `set()` is a great idea. Just create it before the `for`-loop, and add titles in it using method `set.add()`. See the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://itrevolution.com/book-downloads-extra-materials/')
source = source.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
titles = set()

for tl in soup.find_all('img', class_='responsive-img hover-img'):
    title = tl.get('title')
    titles.add(title)

print(titles)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer can we get the title names line separated as it is in post

Comment: I was looking something in the BS4 itself but the `set()` looks to be convincing as it contains unique elements and removes duplicates from a sequence . However i used `join` to interleave a newline in the elements of a collection as `print('\n'.join(titles))`  to get the titles printed into newline.

Comment: Using `join()` was indeed what I would have suggested. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a distinct list here is a slight modification to your code:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source = requests.get('https://itrevolution.com/book-downloads-extra-materials/')
source = source.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
title = []
for tl in soup.find_all('img', class_='responsive-img hover-img'):
  title.append(tl.get('title'))
distinctTitle  = (list(set(title)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Prakhar,  it works but again it gives list output i need the output format as  i my post .